# Resize a view with drag and set original while release

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I would like to tap a view and when it is pressed then it need to be scale downed after releasing the view, it will back to its width and height how do i do? can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Set a proper `OnTouchListener` for your `View` or overwrite `onTouchEvent` method if its a custom view. Like this (the example consist of the first approach):

```
yourView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // apply the change to the dimensions of your view;
                // for example with animation and using scale parameters, like this:
                v.animate().scaleX(0.6f).scaleY(0.6f);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // revert to the normal dimensions of your view
                // for example with animation and using scale parameters, like this:
                v.animate().scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your issue.